# Latex and text in matplotlib title

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I'm trying to show an image with a title that combines normal text with a couple of Latex commands:

```
plt.imshow(w1subtracted2, origin='lower',
          extent=[l_max, -l_max, -b_max, b_max],
          cmap = color_map)
plt.title('W1 disk and central $\pm2\textdegree$ subtracted', fontsize = 'small')
plt.xlabel(xlabel, fontsize = 'small')
plt.ylabel(ylabel, fontsize = 'small')
plt.savefig('w1subtracted2.png')
```

but I can't get the title showing the `\pm` and `\textdegree` to show in Latex style. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It seems you are not using latex (`usetex = True`) but simple MathText. There is no `\textdegree` in MathText.

Using

```
plt.title(r'W1 disk and central $\pm2^\circ$ subtracted', fontsize='small')
```

should give you

[image]

Comment: and where should `usetex = True` go?

Comment: In matplotlib's rcParams. See the documentation here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/usetex.html

Comment: This are the required lines for this  answer to work: ```import matplotlib as mpl ; mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True```

Comment: I like how this answer encourages solutions that don't use `usetex = True`. The built-in MathText seems cleaner where it will work.

Answer (score -4):

Try to run your code through your terminal, as Spyder or Canopy cannot handle Latex commands.

Comment: Hmmm apparently Jupyter doesn't like them either.

Comment: Tried running in Jupyter notebook and Anaconda shell, but neither seem to recognize the Latex commands. Is there no way I can do it in Spyder? I've put Latex commands in legends using Spyder before, using Python 3.