# plt.title in bold removes white space

Tags: matplotlib, latex

I am trying to figure out why my title doesn't appear in bold like it is in regular weight. My goal is to have my title in two parts on the same line. The first part would display the title in bold, and the second part, right after, would display the score of my ML model.

I have tried this :

```
plt.title(r"$\bf{" + region + "}$" + "  (MAPE=%s)" %(mape))
```

And it almost works. But there is no more space between the words of my title (`region`).

If I write this :

```
plt.title(region + str(mape))
```

I have no problem of spacing.

Comment: I guess that the **bold** is not really the issue, but the _tex_ you are using is more likely to be the cause. Try adding `\hspace{2}` between the title parts, ( or more than 2 if you would like)

Comment: Hi Ronpi, thank you for your answer.
Can you tell me why you think that the text is the issue ?
As I wrote in my previous post, when I don't try to change the font weight, the title is ok.
The following line works well :
plt.title(region)

But the next one doesn't :
plt.title(r"$\bf{"+ region + "}$")

And what about the \hspace{2} you proposed to try ? Can you give me an example of use. Because I just don't know exactly where to insert it. 
Thank you

Comment: **tex** (or Latex) not **text**. You are using the `\bf` latex command. Now I also noticed you are wrapping the title with a `$` symbol, which basically mean that the `tex` engine will treat it as an equation, and maybe this is the reason that the whitespaces are being ignored. Maybe take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46698921/latex-and-text-in-matplotlib-title) question also.

Comment: `\bf{...}` is wrong in more than one way. First it is a switch and does not take an argument and second you should not use two-letter font commands but rather `{\bfseries ...}` or `\textbf{...}`. And third: never use math mode for text. Besides the missing spaces it will also completely  mess up the kerning.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I understand it is not the good way to get where I want to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the LaTeX command you're using doesn't preserve spaces... and doesn't work for me in `matplotlib` anyway. Try escaping the spaces in your title text. For example, this works:

```
text = "My title".replace(" ", "\ ")
mape = 0.123
title = "$\mathbf{" + text + f"}}:\ {mape}$"

plt.plot([1, 2, 3])
plt.title(title)
```

Giving:

[image: Resulting plot]

The extra `}` in the third part of the string looks like a typo, but I'm using an f-string and that's how you get the closing brace.

If you'd rather avoid 'math mode' text and do it with `matplotlib` commands, you could do something like this:

```
text = "My title"

plt.plot([1, 2, 3])
plt.suptitle(text, fontweight='bold')
plt.title(mape)
```

This gives:

[image: Using suptitle]

The only disadvantage of `suptitle` (other than the slightly iffy positioning I see in that plot) is that you can only have one for the entire figure, so if you have subplots it won't work for you.

For what it's worth, if it was me, I'd probably put the data inside the plot itself by positioning some text.

Comment: `\bf{hello world}` is indeed incorrect syntax but it would preserve the spaces. The spaces get lost because of the incorrect use of math mode around it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It still doesn't work for me. but yes, I took the problem the wrong way. What I'm trying to do is just having 2 different font weights in the same title. And as I am a total rookie in python and plotting, I just reused a code I found on the internet without understanding it. I'm going to dig a little bit

Comment: I updated my answer. There may be other ways to do it, but I think it works.

Comment: It works !!! Thanks a lot !! I'd like to find something cleaner. More in a Matplotlib way of doing it. But for now you're my hero. Thanks again