# Add Specific Labels and Spacing to Matplotlib Bi-Directional Plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have generated this plot
[image]

From this df:

```
variable        level   margins_fluid   margins_vp
0   volume      1L         0.718          0.690
1   volume      2L         0.501          0.808
2   volume      5L         0.181          0.920
3   MAP         64         0.434          0.647
4   MAP         58         0.477          0.854
5   MAP         52         0.489          0.904
6   Exam       dry         0.668          0.713
7   exam     euvolemic     0.475          0.798
8   exam       wet         0.262          0.893
9   history    COPD        0.506          0.804
10  history   Kidney       0.441          0.778
11  history     HF         0.450          0.832
12  Case    1 (PIV)        0.435          0.802
13  Case    2 (CVC)        0.497          0.809
```

Using this code:

```
font_color = '#525252'
hfont = {'fontname':'Calibri'}
facecolor = '#eaeaf2'
index = fluid_vp_1_2.index
column0 = fluid_vp_1_2['margins_fluid']
column1 = fluid_vp_1_2['margins_vp']
title0 = 'Fluids'
title1 = 'Vasopressors'

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5), facecolor=facecolor, ncols=2, sharey=True)
fig.tight_layout()
axes[0].barh(index, column0, align='center', color='dimgray', zorder=10)
axes[0].set_title(title0, fontsize=18, pad=15, color='black', **hfont)
axes[1].barh(index, column1, align='center', color='lightgray', zorder=10)
axes[1].set_title(title1, fontsize=18, pad=15, color='black', **hfont)
# If you have positive numbers and want to invert the x-axis of the left plot
axes[0].invert_xaxis() 

# To show data from highest to lowest
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

axes[0].set_yticks([])
axes[1].set_yticks([])
```

However, I would like it to exactly match the leftmost panel of this drawing:

[image]

With the variable name appearing once for each set of 3 levels (minus Case, which has two levels), and some added spacing in between each variable group. Any tips?

Comment: Some ideas: you could create an extra row with the variable name for each group that has values of 0 for fluid and vp, then you may just need to find a way to remove every 4th tickmark. Another idea is to explore [subfigures](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subfigures.html) which I think could also be good for this, but I don't think it will look as clean (like they won't all sit in the same contiguous grid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you get started, I couldn't figure out how to center the categories with formatting (it's basically wrapping latex around the text and it seems you loose the justification when you do that).

It may also help to play around with major and minor ticks, for example set the variable names to major ticks and the levels to minor ticks, then you can remove the ticks themselves for majors but keep them for minors.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = """level,margins_fluid,margins_vp
volume,0,0
1L,0.718,0.690
2L,0.501,0.808
5L,0.181,0.920
MAP,0,0
64,0.434,0.647
58,0.477,0.854
52,0.489,0.904
Exam,0,0
dry,0.668,0.713
euvolemic,0.475,0.798
wet,0.262,0.893
history,0,0
COPD,0.506,0.804
Kidney,0.441,0.778
HF,0.450,0.832
Case,0,0
1 (PIV),0.435,0.802
2 (CVC),0.497,0.809"""

data = np.array([a.split(',') for a in s.split("\n")])


fluid_vp_1_2 = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
fluid_vp_1_2['margins_fluid'] = fluid_vp_1_2['margins_fluid'].apply(float)
fluid_vp_1_2['margins_vp'] = fluid_vp_1_2['margins_vp'].apply(float)
fluid_vp_1_2

variableNames = {'volume', 'MAP', 'Exam', 'history', 'Case'}

font_color = '#525252'
hfont = {'fontname':'DejaVu Sans'}
facecolor = '#eaeaf2'
index = fluid_vp_1_2.index#['level']
column0 = fluid_vp_1_2['margins_fluid']
column1 = fluid_vp_1_2['margins_vp']
title0 = 'Fluids'
title1 = 'Vasopressors'

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5), facecolor=facecolor, ncols=2, sharey=True)
axes[0].barh(index, column0, align='center', color='dimgray', zorder=10)
axes[0].set_title(title0, fontsize=18, pad=15, color='black', **hfont)
axes[1].barh(index, column1, align='center', color='lightgray', zorder=10)
axes[1].set_title(title1, fontsize=18, pad=15, color='black', **hfont)
# If you have positive numbers and want to invert the x-axis of the left plot
axes[0].invert_xaxis() 
# To show data from highest to lowest
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

axes[0].yaxis.tick_right()
axes[0].set_yticks(range(len(fluid_vp_1_2)))
maxWordLength = fluid_vp_1_2['level'].apply(lambda x: len(x)).max()
formattedyticklabels = [r'$\bf{'+f"{t.rjust(maxWordLength)}"+r'}$' if t in variableNames else t.rjust(maxWordLength) for t in fluid_vp_1_2['level']]
axes[0].set_yticklabels(formattedyticklabels)
    
fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, but what is up with the x-axis tick labels? I just need them to go from 0-100

Comment: refresh and let me know how it looks, I think I fixed it it after my first answer

Comment: Yay, that works! Thank you. Any idea how to center the Variable name headers like `volume`, `MAP`, etc.?

Comment: you could remove the formatting I added, `r'$\bf{'+f"{t.rjust(maxWordLength)}"+r'}$'` and it will center but it will lose the formatting. Might be worth asking that in a new question. Not totally sure if there's another way to format labels.

Comment: I noticed if I add a space to the variable name in the dataframe creation and in `variableNames`, for example if I converted `History` to `Medical History`, the resultant name in the plot would lose the space, e.g. `MedicalHistory`. How could I fix this? I'm guessing it has something to do with `r'$\bf{'+f"{t.rjust(maxWordLength)}"+r'}$'`

Comment: I think it is probably something with the \bf command see threads [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69003230/plt-title-in-bold-removes-white-space) that might help with fixing that