# Center formatted y-tick labels in bi-directional bar chart matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have generated this bar chart:
[image]

With the help of @Ken Myers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76075788/19980284). My question is, how to center the formatted y-tick labels like `volume`, `MAP`, etc. that act as sort of headers for the variable levels that are plotted. I also suppose I don't really need the y-ticks on each graph, especially not for the bolded header variable names.

Alternatively if I could bring the right graph more to the left, that would help too.

I'm thinking if I can add padding to every third y-axis label, I could move them to the middle, but I'm not sure how to specify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move all the labels to be in between the two plots by slightly changing the code. Firstly, I removed the `rjust()`, so that spaces are not added to the labels. Then, in the `set_ticklabels()`, I've added `ha='center` and `position=(1.15,0)`, which will align the text as needed. You can change the 1.15 if you want to move the labels slightly to the left or right... Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
# Showing only part of changed code from previous answer

#   ....

axes[0].yaxis.tick_right()
axes[0].set_yticks(range(len(fluid_vp_1_2)))
maxWordLength = fluid_vp_1_2['level'].apply(lambda x: len(x)).max()
#formattedyticklabels = [r'$\bf{'+f"{t.rjust(maxWordLength)}"+r'}$' 
#                        if t in variableNames else t.rjust(maxWordLength) for t in fluid_vp_1_2['level']]
formattedyticklabels = [r'$\bf{'+f"{t}"+r'}$' 
                        if t in variableNames else t for t in fluid_vp_1_2['level']]
axes[0].set_yticklabels(formattedyticklabels, ha='center', position=(1.15, 0))
    
fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

**OPTION 2**

As mentioned, if the fields in `variableNames` have a space in them, this gets removed. To avoid this, I used the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76103908/wrapping-y-tick-labels-in-bold-removes-whitespace) to change the answer....

First, in your code above you need to change `history` to `Medical History` in two places - inside the string `s` and inside the array `variableNames`. Then, do NOT use the `formattedticklables`, just `set_yticklables()` to `fluid_vp_1_2['level']`, post which, for the labels in variableNames along, `label.set_fontweight('bold')`

Updated code:

```
#formattedyticklabels = [r'$\bf{'+f"{t.rjust(maxWordLength)}"+r'}$' 
#                        if t in variableNames else t.rjust(maxWordLength) for t in fluid_vp_1_2['level']]
#axes[0].set_yticklabels(formattedyticklabels, ha='center', position=(1.15, 0))

axes[0].set_yticklabels(fluid_vp_1_2['level'], ha='center', position=(1.15, 0))
for label in axes[0].get_yticklabels():
    if label.get_text() in variableNames:
        label.set_fontweight('bold')
```

This will give below plot...

[image]

Comment: I noticed if I add a space to the variable name in the dataframe creation and in `variableNames`, for example if I converted `History` to `Medical History`, the resultant name in the plot would lose the space, e.g. `MedicalHistory`. How could I fix this? I'm guessing it has something to do with `[r'$\bf{'+f"{t}"+r'}$' `

Comment: Hi - yes, when you make the text bold, it removes spaces... Please check under OPTION 2, where I have explained the problem and workaround... hope this helps